# Rails and AJAX remote: true what else is required?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm confused about remote:true in Rails forms, I thought some Javascript was required to make it asynchronous but this just seems to break my page.

Here is a really simple index.html.haml that includes a partial to show all appointments:

```
%h1 Calander

%h2 AppointmentsController
%h3 Make a new appointment

= form_for @appointment, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.text_field :appt_time
  = f.submit 'Make appointment'

#appointments
  =render 'appointments'
```

Here is the previously mentioned partial:

```
    -@appointments.each do |a|
  %h3= a.title
  %p= a.appt_time
```

Controller methods for index and create:

```
 def index
    @appointments = Appointment.order('appt_time ASC')
    @appointment = Appointment.new
  end

  def create
    @appointmet = Appointment.create(appointment_params)
    redirect_to :root
  end
```

Now this works fine.  I can add a new appointment, hit submit and the new appointment shows up without the page refreshing,  I think because I have included `remote: true`.  So do I need to add anything else to handle the request?  Am I violating best practices by not including something to handle this request and relying entirely on remote: true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing more required unless you want some **callback** after **ajax** call. You did not break any conventions. You can read this [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for) to get ride of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back.

Web applications can respond to different request formats. Rails has built-in format handling.

So a request might ask for `index` via HTML, which response with an HTML file. It might also request `index` via JSON, XML, PDF or even JavaScript.

Whenever you add `remote: true` you are telling your form make a `POST` request via JS instead of HTML.

In your views you will have a bunch of HTML.ERB files. These views are request responses.

So to handle a JS request to index, you will need a `app/views/appointements/index.js` file.

This will be sent as the response to the request and the browser will know what to do with a JS response.

In `index.js` you can write JS that will be executed once the response is received.

You can also load partials into the page.

For example:

```
# app/views/appointements/index.js
$('#appointements').html('<%= j render "appointements" %>')
```

Which will render the partial content as a JavaScript string for the response.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Thank you!  What is the "j" for in '<%= j render "appointements" %>'

Comment: Because ERB is file embedement, all Ruby code gets turned into file content. We want the file content to be a JS string `'<div class="blah"></div>'`. This will tell ERB not to write that as file content, but as JS code instead :) If we didn't and the HTML partial content had a `"/n"` newline, then this would become a newline in the file instead of a JS string containing `"/n"`.